# Exporting list of tables contained in *.mdb with ArcPy gives Indentation Error?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap, xml

I'd like to export to excel each of the tables in a .mdb database as separate .xml files.

The code works until the last line which gives an unexpected indentation error, and I'm also struggling with os.path.join, and how to save the excel files to an output folder.

```
import arcpy, os

from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\afullhar\Desktop\Lab6\HydrogetWorkCopy\HydroGet.mdb"

outFolder = r"C:\Users\afullhar\Desktop\Lab6\ExportXML"

tableList = arcpy.ListTables()

for table in tableList:

    print (table)
    in_data = table
    out_file = os.path.join(outFolder, in_data + ".xml") 
    export_option = "DATA"
    storage_type = "NORMALIZED"
    export_metadata = "#"
    arcpy.ExportXMLWorkspaceDocument_management(in_data, out_file, export_option, storage_type, export_metadata)
```

[image: Shows indentation]

Comment: In the Python window to the right, you messed up on the indentation. Where it says arcpy.ExportXML, it should be directly under the export_metadata. Just backspace it so it's lined up correctly.

Comment: So strange-- If I manually backspace as you say and properly indent I get a line 17 indent error instead of line 18 indent error. I'll give it a shot with IDLE.

Comment: Try copying from the code in your question, and pasting it into the window.

Comment: Make sure you are not mixing tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted should not give an indentation error.

I recommend that you open a new Python script and copy/paste the code you posted and run that.

I will be very surprised if you receive an indentation error by doing that.

I suspect that you may have moved the start of the last line left or right in the process of writing your question.

W.r.t. "struggling with os.path.join, and how to save the excel files to an output folder", I think you should research/ask that as a separate question, as per the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).

If you are running your code from the Python window (which in this case I would recommend against) then be extra careful that the prompt and spaces on the last line are identical to the second last.  Your added picture makes it look like you ran the loop, and then tried running the last line outside the loop but with the same indentation as the loop which rightly errors.

If you are using a recent version of ArcGIS for Desktop, then you will find that its Python window takes care of indentation for you - unless you override it like I think you have.

Comment: I am using 4 spaces as my indentation for each line in the for loop.

Comment: I get the same indentation error if I run it in windows command prompt, but I see what you mean.

Comment: I recommend running code like this from IDLE (or another IDE if you have fluency in it).

Comment: A good editor like Notepad++, TextPad or PyWin will show you the difference between TAB and 4 spaces. If you're not sure dedent the entire block and then re-indent. Mixed TAB/n-spaces indentation can cause *havoc* when copy-and-pasting from other code if one uses n-spaces and the other uses single TAB, editors like IDLE and NotePad will not usually show the difference.. so it reads fine in 'human' but python has inconsistent or unexpected indentation errors.

Comment: Thanks Michael! I deleted the spaces which I must have used instead of a tab and the code works. I'll see about using a better editor.